# Remove HTML tag contents from page using Python

Tags: python, html, replace

I have an HTML file like the one below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>

<title>Sezione microbiologia</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" src="./style.css">

</head>

<body>

<div id="content">
    <section id="main">
        <!-- SOME CONTENT... -->
        <h1>Prima diluizione</h1>
        <p>Some content including "prima diluizione"...</p>
        <h1>Seconda diluizione</h1>
        <p>Some content including "seconda diluizione"...</p>
        <h1>Terza diluizione</h1>
        <p>Some content including "terza diluizione"...</p>
    </section>

    <section id="second">
        <!-- SOME CONTENT... -->
    </section>

    <section id="third">
        <!-- SOME CONTENT... -->
    </section>

    <section id="footer">
        <!-- SOME CONTENT... -->
    </section>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Problem description:**

I am trying to modify the headings `<h1>` that contain the the word `diluizione` to replace this word and its prefix with "Diluizione seriale". I tried to do this using Python `replace()`, the problem is that even lines in the `<p>` paragraphs are cut off, whilst I would only like lines in the h1 tags to be modified. On top of that, I still have not managed to find a way to automated taking out the prefix, ie "Prima", "Seconda", "Terza", etc.

**The code I tried with**

I currently came up with this:

```py
with open('./home.html') as file:
    text = file.read()


if "diluizione" in text:
    text = text.replace("diluizione", "diluizione seriale")
```

But this outputs:

```html
<div id="content">
    <section id="main">
        <!-- SOME CONTENT... -->
        <h1>Prima diluizione seriale</h1>
        <p>Some content including "prima diluizione seriale"...</p>
        <h1>Seconda diluizione seriale</h1>
        <p>Some content including "seconda diluizione seriale"...</p>
        <h1>Terza diluizione seriale</h1>
        <p>Some content including "terza diluizione seriale"...</p>
    </section>
```

So as you can see, even text in the `<p>` tags is affected and the headings the prefix is still there.

My **desired output** would be:

```html
<div id="content">
    <section id="main">
        <!-- SOME CONTENT... -->
        <h1>Diluizione seriale</h1>
        <p>Some content including "prima diluizione"...</p>
        <h1>Diluizione seriale</h1>
        <p>Some content including "seconda diluizione"...</p>
        <h1>Diluizione seriale</h1>
        <p>Some content including "terza diluizione"...</p>
    </section>
```

Any help or suggestion is very appreciated, thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the regex through Pythons `re` module to achieve this. In order to only filter text within the `h1` tags, you may use a `positive lookbehind` and a `positive lookahead` strategy.

**Code:**

```py
import re

with open("path/to/home.html") as file:
    text = file.read()

text = re.sub("(?<=<h1>)\w+ \w+(?=</h1>)", "Diluizione seriale", text)

print(text)
```

**Explanation**:

The regular expression `(?<=<h1>)\w+ \w+(?=</h1>)` matches two consecutive word characters contained between `<h1>` and `</h1>`.

**Output**:

```
<!-- SOME CONTENT... -->
<h1>Diluizione seriale</h1>
<p>Some content including "prima diluizione"...</p>
<h1>Diluizione seriale</h1>
<p>Some content including "seconda diluizione"...</p>
<h1>Diluizione seriale</h1>
<p>Some content including "terza diluizione"...</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [html.parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html). Instead of trying to do sting interpolation, rather parse the HTML into a structure and then traverse it from there

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have opted for the regex strategy, but will definitely take a look to html parsers. Thanks for your time.